# JavaScript Quiz?

Tags: javascript, oop

Is this an equivalent 'JavaScript Quiz' site/book to things like :

o Ruby Quiz : http://rubyquiz.com/

o Python Challenge

o Perl Quiz of the Week

I want to improve my object oriented JavaScript skills (i.e. more than striped tables or annoying popups that JavaScript is infamous for). More like 'proper' NodeJS style development.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't come across any as comprehensive as the Python Challenge. Here's a set of questions I came up with though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684917/what-questions-should-a-javascript-programmer-be-able-to-answer/1684945#1684945

This one is a bit more advanced: http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/

Comment: Cheers for the answer - I'll check em out!

Comment: Dead link. The question was removed!

Comment: @SantoshKumar Here's a link from web.archive. https://web.archive.org/web/20130304042231/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684917/what-questions-should-a-javascript-programmer-be-able-to-answer/1684945

Answer (score 0):

You can take a quiz here: http://codefid.info/
This is very good site for learning and practicing not only JS but other front end technologies as well. I recommend this site a lot.